# Which control is suitable for my requirement?

Tags: wpf-controls

In my WPF Application i have requirement that i have window like this

Lab AccessionID:
Lab:
DateTime:

TestName----Result-----Units-----Flag---Ref. Range----Spec. Source-----Per. Site

Lab AccessionID is binding from Lab Order Table
Lab is binding from LabPanel Table
TestName etc are binding all rows from Lab Result Table who has Lab AccessionID.

For every Lab AccessionID this format is repeating and binding data.

What datacontrol i have to use?
Can any one guide me on that?
how to do?

Thanks,
Ramki

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeat the format of displaying binding data you should use ItemsControl.